# what is meaning of {1} in viewtilesxml

Tags: spring

This is my viewstiles xml code.
I don't know meaning of {1}

in my web-init>views>home folder, i have two files - home.jsp , home1.jsp

```
<definition name="home/*" extends="page.layout">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home/{1}.jsp" />
</definition>
```

what is meaning of {1},home/*, page.layout?

Answer (score 1):

It's `Apache tiles`.

Suppose you have the following definition:

```
<definition name="bank/user" template="/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/header.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="body"   value="/user.jsp"/>
</definition>

<definition name="bank/account" template="/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/header.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="body"   value="/account.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

don't you think if will be much better if we could do it like this:

```
<definition name="bank/*" template="/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/header.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="body"   value="/{1}.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

**{1} refers to the star's value which is "user" in that case**

*** eliminates the repetition**

I hope that's clear.
For more infos: [see](https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/wildcard.html)